# What is the limit of TCP connections per machine using TSUNG?

Tags: tcp, erlang, ejabberd, tsung

I want to generate a lot of requests using TSUNG.

My configuration file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/local/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="notice" dumptraffic="false" version="1.0">
  <clients>
    <client host="localhost" maxusers="70000" use_controller_vm="true"/>
  </clients>

<servers>
   <server host="myhost" port="5222" type="tcp"/>
</servers>

<load>
  <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="70000" unit="second">
    <users arrivalrate="10" unit="second"/>
  </arrivalphase>
  </load>

<options>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="70000"/>
<option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="my-domain"/>
  <option name="file_server" id="userdb" value="/root/userdata.csv"/>
</options>

<sessions>
<session probability="100" name="xmpp-connection" type="ts_jabber" bidi="true" $

  <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="userdb" delimiter=";" order="iter">
         <var name="userid"/>
   </setdynvars>
          <transaction name="initial_stream">
        <request subst="true">
           <jabber type="connect" ack="local">
                 <xmpp_authenticate username="tsung%%_userid%%" passwd="tsung%%_userid%%"/>
          </jabber>
         </request>
   </transaction>

   <thinktime value="2"/>

   <transaction name="authenticate">
       <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl" ack="local"/> </request>
       <request> <jabber type="connect" ack="local"/> </request>
       <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl_bind" ack="local"/> </request>
       <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl_session" ack="local"/> </request>
   </transaction>
    <transaction name="roster_get">
       <request>  <jabber type="iq:roster:get" ack="local"/> </request>
   </transaction>


   <request> <jabber type="presence:initial" ack="no_ack"/> </request>
    <for from="1" to="28" incr="1" var="counter">
       <request> <jabber type="raw" ack="no_ack" data="
"/></request>
       <thinktime value="60" random="false"/>
   </for>

   <for from="1" to="30" incr="1" var="counter">
       <request> <jabber type="raw" ack="no_ack" data="
"/></request>
      <thinktime value="60" random="false"/>
   </for>

  <transaction name="close">
     <request> <jabber type="close" ack="no_ack"/> </request>
   </transaction>

 </session>
</sessions>
</tsung>
```

As per the documentation of TSUNG, I can hit the server using multiple client ips (one machine)
http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-client-server.html

*Several virtual IP can be used to simulate more machines. This is very useful when a load-balancer use the client’s IP to distribute the traffic among a cluster of servers.*

```
<clients>
  <client host="louxor" weight="1" maxusers="800">
    <ip value="10.9.195.12"></ip>
    <ip value="10.9.195.13"></ip>
  </client>
  <client host="memphis" weight="3" maxusers="600" cpu="2"/>
</clients>
```

I want to find out how many connections per one machine I can generate using TSUNG.

I have a 32 GB, 8 core machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on two factors:

1. The maximum number of simultaneously open Erlang ports.
2. The maximum amount of open file description in your operating system.

For information about the first one see [open ports](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#ports) in the 10.2 System Limits section of the Advanced Erlang document. It can be changed using the `+Q` option when starting the Erlang VM. The default is 16384. And the current limit can be checked using [`erlang:system_info/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info-1):

```
erlang:system_info(port_limit).
```

For second information simply `ulimit -n` in the shell. How to change this value depends on the operating system but it's a popular topic so you will easily be able to search for instructions.

Comment: Hey is it possible to run multiple tsung clients on the same machine?

Comment: I don't know about Tsung but certainly it's very much possible to run multiple Erlang VMs on the same machine. Considering that Tsung is an Erlang application there isn't a reason why running multiple Erlang VMs each one running its own Tsung wouldn't be possible (unless specific Tsung requirements, which is quite unlikely). If only your node has enough power, go for it. On the other hand, what would be the difference between running multiple Tsung installations on the same machine and running one generating more load (with more connections)? Erlang scales pretty well on multicore machines.

Comment: The result also depends on the number of IP you can use  on your server.